# CSS background image with img divs

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to work out how to work with img divs on a grid. The background image of this grid contains a border, when I try to inspect the element element, the img divs start from the absolute top-left hand corner instead of slightly away from on the actual checkerboard patterned image, which has a thick border around it (950 * 500 - 18 columns wide by 9 rows). Does anyone know How I could tackle this problem?

CSS

```
body
{
    background: #000000 url('gfx/bg.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1280px; height:720px;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: tivo-normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}




#GameGrid
{
    position: absolute;
    /*width: 806px; height: 496px; top: 120px; left: 92px;*/
    width: 950px; 
    height: 500px;
    top: 50px; 
    left: 92px;
    background: transparent url('gfx/Game_0003_GAMEGRID.png') center center no-repeat;
}

#GameGrid > div
{
    /*width: 62px; height: 62px;*/
    width: 52px; height: 52px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}

#GameGrid > div > img
{
    /*width: 62px; height: 62px;*/
    width: 52px; height: 52px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate your problem? Maybe using a snippet or a fiddle? Perhaps `background-origin: border-box` be useful?

Comment: Use jsfiddle.net to post your user interface related issues.

Comment: accompanied HTML is required and provide a demo.

Answer (score 0):

If I calculate by the values you are given: 18 columns each 52px wide that makes it 936px and your GameGrid is 950px. So I am assuming the 14px are taken by the border i.e. 7px each side

So, you can just add a padding in GameGrid

```
{
    position: absolute;
    /*width: 806px; height: 496px; top: 120px; left: 92px;*/
    width: 950px; 
    height: 500px;
    top: 50px; 
    left: 92px;
    background: transparent url('gfx/Game_0003_GAMEGRID.png') center center no-repeat;
    padding:7px;
}
```

Set specific top,right,bottom,left paddings if they are required specifically.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the cellpading="0" attribute to your  tag. You can also add a CSS rule to prevent padding, something like:

```
#GameGrid td, #GameGrid th{
  padding:0px;
  position:relative;
}
```

and maybe add top:0px; to your #GameGrid > div > img. An example could help us to understand better your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Resorted to modify the image file and removed the border around the grid. Created another div with an image of just the grid border and aligned it to the grid div.